# Swift Open App From Widget & Push View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am using the following (in swift) in a widget to open a news article in Safari.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if let item = items?[indexPath.row] {
            if let context = extensionContext {
                context.openURL(item.link, completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is open the app that goes along with the widget, and push the view controller hosting that article to the user.  That way, it all stays in house.  However, being new enough to Swift, I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.  Any suggestions?  My app's first tab is the one that contains the TableView of articles.